# C# - Create a new instance of a host-class within a dll-project

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a main application with a class "Apple" and a separate dll project where I want to create a new instance of "Apple". Both projects (MainApplication and Dll-Project) are separate projects but both are in the same solution. Background is that I want to have some classes (in this example the class 'DllClass') as a dll.

**MainApplication:**

```cs
 using AppLib;

 namespace SpaceOne
 {
    public class Main
    {
    }

    public class Apple
    {
       public Apple(DllClass someThing)
       {
          // Do some constructor stuff
       }
    }
 }
```

**DLL-Project:** "AppLib"

```cs
using MainApplication;

namespace SpaceTwo
{  
   public class DllClass
   {
      Apple foo = new Apple(this); // <= Here occurs the fault
   }
}
```

Why does it show this fault message:

> The best overloaded method match for SpaceOne.Apple.Apple(DllClass)
>   has some invalid arguments

If I copy the DllClass to my MainApplication and try it there it works just fine. But I can't create a new instance of Apple from my DLL-Project despite the fact that I have imported the MainApplication as a reference and via 'using MainApplication'.

How can I create a new instance of Apple from my DLL-Project?

---

**Update:** This is just a code example which does not compile and should just show the rough structure of my code.

Comment: That error doesn't match the code you show. Also your code (aside from the line you mention) does not compile at all. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: why does your class declaration have `()` That is what is causing the problem

Comment: To access a class of your main project, your dll project would have to _reference_ that main project. But that of course seems the wrong direction. Normally your main project would reference the dll to use classes that the dll provides. But as it stands, your code has other issues: the `()` in the class declaration as well as using `this` in a `static` context (field initialization)

Comment: What is the reason of instantiating a class defined in high level module inside low level class library? You should move the `Apple` class to separate class library project and then referrence it in `AppLib` instead. This approach is more desirable IMO.

Comment: I don't know how this example would ever work.  It looks to me like you have a circular dependency.  How would this ever compile?

Comment: @WooHoo It could be made to work if the classes were in the same project (by moving the `Apple foo` instantiation into a constructor.)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I create a new instance of Apple from my DLL-Project?

You can't, Apple in your Main Application uses a class from the DLL-Project - DllClass.  So for this to compile Main Application must have a reference to the DLL-Project.

The DLL-Project is using Apple from the Main Application.  So DLL-Project must have a reference to the Main Application.

But this will not compile, you have a circular dependency.  To compile Main Application you would need a compiled DLL-Project, but to compile DLL-Project you would need a compiled Main Application, but you can't compile Main Applicaiton until you have a compiled DLL-Project.....hence circular dependency.

Why not move Apple into the DLL-Project?

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. The problem is that Apple has some other dependencies and so i had to move all the dependent classes also into DLL-Project. One of this classes creates a new window at initalisation what causes additional problems.